# Bash ERR trap halting program

Tags: bash, bash-trap

This trap on `ERR` halts the script. Other examples show that a trap can be used to continue program execution, so why does this halt?

```
#!/bin/sh -e
trap 'echo error' ERR
echo begin
false
echo end
```

Returns

```
$ ./test.sh
begin
$
```

Answer (score 2):

`ERR` traps are still affected by the shell's `errexit` option (set -e). The problem here is that the shebang sets `errexit`. This will work as expected:

```
#!/bin/sh
trap 'echo error' ERR
echo begin
false
echo end
```

returning

```
$ ./test.sh
begin
error
end
$
```

`errexit` is very aggressive. It will instantly kill the script if any statement is non-true.

This will push you as a developer to write very defensively. For example, you cannot ever use `$?` with `errexit` because the script itself will not continue if the exit code is non-zero. This "push the developer to get it perfect" approach is useful for some scenarios, e.g. commonly errexit is used to run very early boot scripts when automatically provisioning a system.

If you find yourself in an `errexit` scenario but needing to handle expected errors, here is the common approach:

```
#!/bin/sh -e 
trap 'echo error' ERR
echo begin
false || { echo "It was false"; } 
echo end
```

Which will output:

```
begin
It was false
end
```

Note that the trap is still not fired, because no error happened. As far as I can tell, the "error" condition referred to by ERRtrap and errexit is functionally identical